# How to add zip file and tar.gz file links on Github pages

Tags: github, github-pages

I am creating my OSS project page with Github pages.

I selected the theme which is provided Github below.

[image]

The theme example shows the zip file and tar.gz file link icons.

However, these icons are not shown up in my project page.

[image]

Is there anyone who knows how to show the icons?

Answer (score 5):

The download link icons are enabled in the

> _config.yml

file of your github.io home directory by adding

> show_downloads: true

Note, the link(s) are to file(s) that contain the entire repository.

The documentation is under the "Customizing" heading at https://github.com/pages-themes/slate